# Removing metadata with PowerPoint 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, privacy, metadata, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I'm looking for a solution to remove metadata from .PPTX files on Mac with PowerPoint 2011. On Windows, there is a Microsoft utility called Document Inspector. Does anyone know of anything similar on Mac OS X?

I'm hoping to find a solution to remove the same metadata as or more than as Document Inspector for Windows does (see MS KB article `Ff862071` for metadata removed).

So far, I have found:

1. A python script/Automator solution located [here](http://andrewfong.com/blog/2011/10/04/remove-notes-from-powerpoint-pptx/), but it only removes slide notes.
2. A related Microsoft help article `JJ984201`, but it only suggests clearing the fields on the Summary tab of `File -> Properties...` which excludes most metadata.
3. A [related article](http://safecomputing.umich.edu/protect-personal/metadata.php) from the Univ. of Michigan that gives menu options not present in PowerPoint 2011 (which are present in Word and Excel 2011).

I couldn't post more links, so hopefully the MS KB articles are easy to find.

**EDIT:** Please let me know if this is better posted in softwarerecs or elsewhere. Feedback on asking questions appreciated.